# How to send by data from API to UI and display response data as image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, http

I have simple CRUD application asp.net in the back and Angular 7 in the front.
In my database, each user has the image stored as a byte array. How to convert byte data and send it to the client properly to display them as photo later.

Comment: If you have asp then you are communicating using html.  The image is binary so you have to use Base 64 string to convert binary to a string that can be sent to client.

Comment: I created HttpGet method in .net core in my controller and it returns Ok(base64Data). How to handle it on the client side in angular project?

Comment: You need to get Image from data.  So you have to convert base64 data to byte[].  One way is to use a Memory Stream.  Read byte to stream.   Then get Image from stream.  Make sure after filling Memory Stream you set position to zero before reading.

Answer (score -1):

you can send it as file and in Front end you can get it as blob ( not json response ) and display it, give it a try plz

Answer (score -1):

you can display image from base64 byte data directly. [This example can help you](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2017/10/display-byte-image-from-rest-web-service.html)